# CSS Styling after PHP Template was Altered for WordPress Plug-in

Tags: php, css

I'm working on a WordPress site where the previous developer exposed team members' e-mail addresses to spambots by using standard 'mailto' links.  Here is how that was coded in the page template:

`<?php if(get_field('email_id'))?><li><a href="mailto:<?php the_field('email_id');?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>`

That yielded a clickable link via the 'envelope button', as seen here: https://monosnap.com/file/hGYBGsMsnzU1ENd8sKFYE1vtuiKzPS

So to solve the spambot problem, I installed a plug-in called [PHPEnkoder](http://www.weaselhat.com/phpenkoder/), which required that line of the page template to be coded as follows:

`<?php if(get_field('email_id'))?><li><?php echo enkode_mailto(get_field('email_id'),get_field('email_id'));?><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>`

Originally, the 'mailto' link was wrapped inside the `a href` tag, but since PHPEnkoder generates that a different way, it's changed the outputted HTML and the CSS rules aren't applying plus the entire 'button' functionality isn't working, as seen here: https://monosnap.com/file/YpuReWPyNUU1TWwWAYY8evwipBUZ7L

I'm not sure whether this needs to be fixed on the PHP side (by adjusting the above template page code), or by adding some CSS styling...

Either way, I'm not able to figure this out and could definitely use some help!

Answer (score 0):

Without viewing the site entirely, and merely looking at your posted markup, it appears you are missing some markup. Specially the **anchor** markup :`<a href="mailto:<?php ?>">`.

This:

`<li><?php echo enkode_mailto(get_field('email_id'),get_field('email_id'));?><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>`

*Should probably be...*

`<li><a href="mailto:<?php echo enkode_mailto(get_field('email_id'),get_field('email_id'));?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></li>`

Note where the **`<a href="mailto:`** was added and the closing **`">`**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Scott.  Unfortunately, that did not work - it just produced the result as seen here: https://monosnap.com/file/CEx9Ux3jjsn7ug4tXbs1wkpfLGaqdF

Comment: It's not possible to solve markup/code issues looking at screenshots. Sorry. It's like trying to repair an automobile merely by listening to it.... you may get an idea of what may be the issue, but without actually looking, you can never be certain.